# "Create NSManagedObject subclass" creates .h and .m instead of .swift files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, xcode8

I am having an issue when I renamed one of my CoreData Entities from "ProductCase" to "ProductPack".

It will now only generate `ProductPack+CoreDataClass.h/.m` and `ProductPack+CoreDataProperties.h/.m` instead of `ProductPack.swift` and `ProductPack+CoreDataProperties.swift`

I rolled back all changes and tried it multiple times I also tried changing the "Codegen" property to "Manual/None", "Class definition" and "Category/Extension"

I also tried quitting Xcode and restarting my computer.

Is there some setting that I have changed by accident? Or is this a known issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue "Code Generation Language" under "file inspector" was set to objective-c instead of Swift.

Not sure how it got changed but a simple fix.

Comment: Keep an eye on that setting - in the beta I found it resetting quite often and I don't know whether it got fixed.

Comment: This affects automatically created classes for the data modeler, so its the best solution.